# Antialiased effect on line in svg

Tags: svg

I created a simple SVG: https://thomas-guettler.de/tmp/bust-in-silhouette.svg

The lines are "hard". I would like to have soft borders, like antialiased fonts look like.

How to do this?

Update: [shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) is not what I am looking for. I want to have the edge blured. Like this:

[image: blured-line]

Comment: [running Code Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @RobertLongson I updated the question. shape-rendering does not help here.

Comment: Sounds like you ought to apply a gaussian blur filter to the shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **feGaussianBlur** filter:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
<defs>
    <filter id="blur-filter" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1.5" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0,-70)">
    <circle style="fill:none;stroke:#e4e4e4;stroke-width:3" id="path12" cx="36.571712" cy="112.38668" r="14.648677" filter="url(#blur-filter)"/>
    <path id="path16" style="fill:none;stroke:#e4e4e4;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 44.558467,124.4381 c -0.785324,6.57119 12.819094,2.84752 14.563786,9.83637 -0.136789,8.75076 1.389218,15.51609 -1.00371,16.20504 -3.548352,3.55851 -37.719446,1.47838 -43.074237,-0.51107 -2.069788,-3.00382 -0.76269,-4.39621 -1.193106,-12.72626 0.649711,-9.64531 16.184933,-5.35944 15.200858,-11.71705" filter="url(#blur-filter)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```